# What is this diagram?

Tags: fractions

This diagram plots every irreducible fraction between 0 and 1 as points, where a point's x coordinate is the fraction's value (from 0 to 1) and its y coordinate is the fraction's denominator (from 2 to whatever the maximum is).

[image: Denominators for denominators from 2 to 20]

[image: The diagram for denominators up to 100]

It makes really nice patterns the further the denominators go and I'd really like to know more about it. I think I remember finding it on Wikipedia or something a long time ago with a name along the lines of "the stars of x" or "the towers of y".

Maybe it's just nothing, though.

Comment: The $y$-value looks like it's the negative of the denominator? Or else the diagram is drawn "computer style" with x increasing from left to right and y increasing from top to bottom.

Comment: one possibility  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence

Comment: @MishaLavrov right, it seems to be Farey denominators, upside down from the plots on wikipedia I think one can click directly on this image link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#/media/File:Farey_sequence_denominators_25.svg

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, that's right, I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the graph of the reciprocal of Thomae's
function.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)